# Nuxt.js trigger middleware after store dispatch

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to create a simple app with authentication using **Nuxt.js**. I have an `auth` middleware which redirects me to `login` page if i am not logged in. The problem is in `logout` function which should check if there is an `auth` middleware on this page and redirect me to `login` page if it is. I was trying to write

```
methods: {
    async logout() {
        try {
            await this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout');
            this.$router.push(this.$route.fullPath);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

but `router.push` doesn't trigger middleware. What can I do with `logout` function to make it work?

(The main question is how to manually rerun middleware on the page without a hard refresh to check if the page requires authentication).

The problem is, basically, that if `logout` is called on a page that needs authentication, after 'pushing' current path to router the middleware on the current page need to be run, so the user is redirected to `login` page instead of staying on the page that needs user to be authenticated.

Comment: Totally not clear whats your problem

Comment: @Aldarund, mentioned this in question, please, recheck.

Comment: Why just not redirect user to login in logout?

Comment: @Aldarund, e.g. `logout` on `/` page shouldn't redirect user to `/login`

Comment: so check if its not / and then redirect

Comment: @Aldarund, not only `/` shouldn't redirect me but also every page which has `auth` middleware. That's the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$router.push` doesn't refresh page on the same path. You can try `$router.go()`.

If you call `go()` without an argument, the current page is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks! But is there more SPA variant without refreshing a page?

Comment: Did you find a SPA solution?

Comment: oemera.. did you?

Answer (score 0):

For the googlers

I have a hacky solution.. Use `router.push()` with a query param. Then remove the query param in the middleware.

### Example

Somewhere in your code:

```
const router = useRouter()
const route = useRoute()

let query: any = {...route.query}
query.hash = uniqid()
router.push({ query })
```

Middleware:

```
const router = useRouter()

if (to.query?.hash) {
    let query: any = {...to.query}
    delete query.hash

    router.replace({ query })
}
```